# Extended Siddhi event-table to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, complex-event-processing, siddhi

I need to use an event-table with connection to a PostgreSQL db on execution plan.

I tried to extend the Siddhi extension RDBMS event table (from siddhi-master branch) and while doing the jUnit tests I can interact successful with the database.

I add the eventtable.siddhiext file to conf folder and the .jar to dropins folder but when I try to access through the execution plan i cannot establish the connection. Moreover, I could create the PostgreSQL Datasource with no problems, so the cep can reach the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catarina, Actually you don't have to add the eventtable.siddhiext to conf folder.. What you have to do is wrap the *.siddhiext with the jar file and copy to the dropins folder (As shown in [1]) ..

Here there are few things that you need to keep in mind.
- Since, we have an OSGI runtime. Please have a unique package name for your event table extension.
- Have a unique name for siddhiext file.. For example, postgres.siddhiext ..

[1] https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/tree/master/modules/siddhi-extensions/event-table/src/main/resources